# How do I write the values of two or more variables at the same line of a .txt file in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to save the values of three variables, V1, V2, V3 in the same line of a .txt file separated by |. Now I use this code:

```
 Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
   file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("test.txt", True)
   file.Writeline("The Value of V1"+"|"+"The Value of V2"+"|"+"The Value of V3")
   file.Close()
```

and the output is this:

> The Value of V1|The Value of V2|The Value of V3

but I actually need to save the values of V1, V2 and V3 that are doubles and not strings.

Thanks a lot

Comment: V1.ToString() doesn't work?

Comment: So how about `file.Writeline(V1+"|"+V2+"|"+V3)` then? That's assuming those are actually the names of your variables. You might possibly need to use ToString() to help. It's a bit unclear what the actual problem is, or what you're struggling to understand. Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Try reading the documentation for that WriteLine method. You should have already done so and everything you need is there.

Comment: Thanks V1.ToString() worked

Comment: The concatenation character in vb.net is the ampersand &.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0) or [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings),

```
    Dim v1 As Integer = 1
    Dim v2 As Integer = 2
    Dim v3 As Integer = 3
    Dim s As String = String.Format("The Value of V1 {0}|The Value of V2 {1}|The Value of V3 {2}",
                                        v1, v2, v3)

    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("test.txt", True)
    file.WriteLine(s)
    file.Close()
```

The WriteLine has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamWriter_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_) that incorporates String.Format.